# How to add a mouseListener for each object in an arrayList and detect which object was clicked on?

Tags: java

The Tree class

```
public class Tree {


private GeneralPath treePath;
public int tX, tY;


public Tree (int tx, int ty) {
    tX = tx;
    tY = ty;
    int xPoints[] = { 20, 0, 20, 0, 30, 60, 40, 60, 40};
    int yPoints[] = { 100, 66, 50, 33, 0, 33, 50, 66, 100};

    treePath = new GeneralPath();
    treePath.moveTo(xPoints[0], yPoints[0]);

    for (int index = 1; index < xPoints.length; index++) {
        treePath.lineTo(xPoints[index], yPoints[index]);
        }

    treePath.closePath();
}


public void drawTree(Graphics2D g2) {

    AffineTransform moveIt = new AffineTransform();
    g2.translate(tX, tY);
    g2.scale(0.4, 0.4);
    g2.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
    g2.fill(treePath);
    g2.setTransform(moveIt);
}


}




public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
private ArrayList<Tree> trees = new ArrayList<Tree>();

public DrawingPanel(JFrame frame) {
    this.frame = frame;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        trees.add(new Tree(100 + (30*i), (100 + (40*j))));
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      paintBackground(g2);

      for (int i = 0; i < trees.size(); i++) {
            Tree tempT = trees.get(i);
            // if bug i and bug j collide and is head-on

        tempT.drawTree(g2);
      }

}
}
```

How would I go about adding a mouseListener to detect on a mouseClick which object (if any) was clicked?

Do I add the mouseListener to the arrayList? Or to each object?

How would I return the object I clicked on?

Does java have some way of getting back the object you just clicked on? Or do I need to setup a bounding box for the tree? (Which I already have)

The bounding box is a rectangle (tx, ty, tx+60, ty+100) with the following (x, y, w, h).

Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you moving the entire tree en mass? If so, then I'd probably use the bounding rectangle.

Comment: Did you mean the whole array of trees? I'm not. Each tree is individually positioned at an equal distance with a for-loop. But I want each tree to individually disappear when I click on it.